# Possible to override timeout on js Management SDK Uploads?

Tags: javascript, contentful-management

I'm trying to upload files that are between 20-100MB in size, but they always fail to upload in under 30 seconds. This is where the timeout is configured, contentful-sdk-core/dist/es-modules/create-http-client.js:

```
var defaultConfig = {
insecure: false,
retryOnError: true,
logHandler: function logHandler(level, data) {
  if (level === 'error' && data) {
    var title = [data.name, data.message].filter(function (a) {
      return a;
    }).join(' - ');
    console.error('[error] ' + title);
    console.error(data);
    return;
  }
  console.log('[' + level + '] ' + data);
},
// Passed to axios
headers: {},
httpAgent: false,
httpsAgent: false,
timeout: 30000,
proxy: false,
basePath: ''
  };
var config = _extends({}, defaultConfig, options);
```

Can I override these settings to allow for a more generous timeout?

Edit: I have tried changing them directly in the config options, and it works, but I don't think this is a sustainable way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Contentful here:

https://www.contentfulcommunity.com/t/large-file-upload-timeout/607/4

Basically, just add a timeout when creating the space, like this:

```
var contentful = require('contentful')
var client = contentful.createClient({
// This is the space ID. A space is like a project folder in Contentful terms
space: <space-id>,
// This is the access token for this space. Normally you get both ID and the 
token in the Contentful web app
accessToken: <delivery-token>,
timeout: 999999
})
```